# unrar multiple files wity multiple files

Tags: linux, 7z, rar

I have 1000s of rar files and list of password in txt. i want to unrar all those files trying all passwords.

Tried:

```
for file in "$(ls *.rar)"; do for f in "$(cat pass.txt)"; do unrar x -p"${f} "${file}; done; done
```

But not working. Tried it with unrar 7za but still fails

Comment: See [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: thanks got it work

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in ./*.rar; do for f in `cat pass.txt`; do unrar x -p"${f} "${file}; done; done
```